# How to add validation on clicking outside input in angular form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an input for email as shown below

[image]

This is the code:

```
<form [formGroup]="emailGroupForm" (ngSubmit)="formSubmitted()>
    <mch-token-field formControlName="emails" htmlId="email-token-field" [hideClear]="true" [hideCount]="true"
            class="md-margin__bottom--none md-margin__top--s md-h6 md-body--bold" [tokenValidators]="emailValidators"></mch-token-field>

</form>
```

`mch-token-field` is a customized input component which is used across multiple components and I am not allowed to change anything in this component. Now, when I type something inside the email input and press enter, the email gets added. But what I want is to add the email when I click outside the box after typing, like once I touched the component.

I want the below validation to happen also when we click outside the email box:

```
 <div class="md-h6 md-body--bold md-color--red-50"
          *ngIf="emailGroupForm.controls.emails.touched && emailGroupForm.controls.emails.errors">
        <md-icon name="error" class="md-margin__right--xs error-icon"></md-icon>
        <ng-container *ngIf="emailGroupForm.controls.emails.errors.invalidEmail">
          One or more emails seems to be invalid
        </ng-container>
```

And in my `.ts` file :

```
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

 emailValidators = [ this.emailPatternValidator() ];

  emailPatternValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (!control.value || this.emailPattern.test(control.value)) {
        return null;
      }
      return {
        invalidEmail: control.value,
      };
    };
  }
```

How do I add the validation when I enter something in the email input box and click outside? Can I make use of `emailGroupForm.controls.emails.touched` in some way for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you create the formGroup, here is a working example:

Typescript file:

```
  emailPattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,20}$');

 emailPatternValidator = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  if (!control.value || this.emailPattern.test(control.value)) {
   return null;
  }
  return {
   invalidEmail: control.value,
 };
};

formGroup = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl(null, [this.emailPatternValidator]),
});
```

HTML Template:

```
<mat-form-field  >
 <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
 <input matInput formControlName="email" />
 <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.email?.errors?.invalidEmail">'The email format is invalid
 </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```